# react native list view design

Tags: css, react-native

I have tried to design the screen in react native but its hard divide a screen column and row like ionic and angular
[Output of that below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGYJS.jpg)

```
 <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>   
<View style={{flex:1}}>    
<View style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
  <Text>1003234</Text>
  <Text>Info Test........</Text>
  </View>
</View>
<View style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
<Text style={{backgroundColor:"red",borderRadius:10,padding:2,
marginRight:10,marginTop:5,fontSize:12}}>Inprogress</Text>
</View> 
</View>`
```

[exactly what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqk2v.png)

Comment: please add a codesanbox link with the working code

Comment: this code doesn't looks like the screenshot that you have posted.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-uozsd?fontsize=14

Comment: check it now @XenioGracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with My Own code(FlatList view with design and search bar data from api) In that code i have removed my api call services you can try your own

[Output Here(Check Before You Try)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6esis.jpg)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet,FlatList,ScrollView,ActivityIndicator} from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from 'react-native-picker-dropdown';
import Icon5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
import { SearchBar, Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

// create a component
class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            data:[],
            text: '',
            language:'self',
            ready: false,
            searchText: "",
            filteredData: [],
            backupData:[]
            }
      this.onValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this)
      this.arrayholder=[];
    }




search (searchText)  {
  this.setState({searchText: searchText});
    console.log(searchText)
  let text = searchText.toLowerCase();
    let trucks = this.state.data;

    // search by food truck name
    let filteredName = trucks.filter((truck) => {
      return truck.title.toLowerCase().match(text); 
    });

    // if no match and text is empty
    if( text == '') {
      console.log('change state');
        this.setState({
          data: this.state.backupData
        });
      }
      else if(!text ){
        console.log("myname")
        this.setState({data:[]})
      }
    // if no name matches to text output
    else if(!Array.isArray(filteredName) && !filteredName.length) {
      console.log("not name");
      this.setState({
        data: [],
      });
    }
    // if name matches then display
    else if(Array.isArray(filteredName)) {
      console.log('Name');
      this.setState({
        data: filteredName,
      });
    }
};


showEmptyListView = () => {
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 10 }}>
          <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{"No Data to Display"}</Text>
      </View>
  )
}

handleValueChange(language) {
  this.setState({ language })
}

renderRow = (item, index) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>   
<View style={{flex:1}}>

<View style={{flexDirection:"column",alignItems:"flex-start"}}>
  <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
  <Text style={{marginLeft:12,marginTop:5,marginBottom:5,fontWeight:"bold",color:"black"}}>{item.number}</Text>

  <Icon5 name="arrow-circle-up" size={15} style={{ marginTop:8,marginLeft:8, color: '#af2a5b', }}/>  
    <Text style={{marginLeft:5,marginTop:5,marginBottom:5,fontWeight:"bold",color:"#af2a5b"}}>{item.priority}</Text>
</View>
  <Text style={{marginLeft:12,marginBottom:5,fontWeight:"bold",color:"black"}}>{item.title}</Text>
  <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
  <Icon5 name="calendar-alt" size={15} style={{ marginLeft:12,marginBottom:5 }}/>    
  <Text style={{marginLeft:8,marginBottom:5}}>{item.assignedDate}</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
  <Icon5 name="user-alt" size={15} style={{ marginLeft:12,marginBottom:5 }}/>    
  <Text style={{marginLeft:8,marginBottom:5}}>{item.createdBy}</Text>
  </View>

  </View>

</View>

<View style={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
  <Text style={{color:"#f6b073",backgroundColor:"#fcd8b8",borderRadius: 10,padding:3,marginRight:10,marginTop:5,fontSize:12}}>{item.state}</Text>
</View>
</View>
    );
  }
renderHeader = () => {
          return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <View style={styles.listItemContainer}>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',backgroundColor: '#fff',color: '#fff',
                        width: '100%',height: 43,}}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <View style={{ width: '45%', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 7, paddingBottom: 7, color: '#fff', }} >
  <Picker  mode="dropdown"  style={{width:150}}
   selectedValue={this.state.language}
   onValueChange={this.onValueChange} >
  <Picker.Item label="My Task" value="self" />
  <Picker.Item label="My Group" value="group" />
</Picker>
                </View>

                <View style={{ width: '55%', justifyContent: 'center', paddingTop: 7, paddingBottom: 7, color: '#fff', }} >

            <SearchBar
            inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 55, borderWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, height: 25 }}
            containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#g5g5g5', borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 55, borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, width: '100%', marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 10, height: 40 }}
            placeholder="Search Here..."
            inputContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 55, height: 25 }}           
            onChangeText={searchText => this.search(searchText)}           
            value={this.state.searchText}
          />
                </View>
        </View>
             </View>
                 </View>
                    </View>
          )
      }
      renderFooter = () => {
          return(
              <View>
                  <Text>Footer</Text>
              </View>
          )
      }
    render() {
      if (this.state.ready) {

        return (

        <FlatList style={{flex: 1,}}
        data={this.state.filteredData && this.state.filteredData.length > 0 ? this.state.filteredData : this.state.data}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          this.renderRow(item, index)
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
        ListEmptyComponent={this.showEmptyListView()}
        enableEmptySections={true}

        style={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
      />
        );
      }
      else{
        return (
          <ActivityIndicator
            animating={true}
            style={{flex: 1,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              height: 80}}
            color="#2F80ED"
            size="large"
          />
        );

      }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listItemContainer: {

    flex: 1,
    marginBottom:10,
    // paddingBottom: 15,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
},
})

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flatlist
Use below code to apply styles to your List

```
          <FlatList style={Styles.container}
                    data={this.props.listData}
                    extraData={this.state.selectedItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        this.renderRow(item, index)
                    )}
                    ListEmptyComponent={this.showEmptyListView()}
                />
```

Your row render can look like this.

```
renderRow = (item, index) => {

    return (
        <TouchableHighlight key={index} onPress={() => this.onPressAction(item)} >
            <View style={Styles.listItemContainer}>
                <View style={Styles.listDesign}>
                    <View style={Styles.imageLength}>
                        {
                            item.imageUrl == '' ?
                                <Image
                                    source={require("./../../assets/images/default-display.png")}
                                    style={{ resizeMode: "cover", width: '100%', height: 100 }} /> :
                                <Image
                                    source={{ uri: item.thumbnailImageUrl }}
                                    style={{ resizeMode: "cover", width: '100%', height: 100 }} />
                        }

                    </View>
                    <View style={[Styles.columnAlign, Styles.contentWidth]}>
                        <View style={[Styles.justifyEnd, Styles.imageContainer]}>

                                    <View style={Styles.justifySpaceAround}>
                                        <Image
                                            source={require("./../../assets/images/anyImage.png")}
                                            style={{ resizeMode: "cover", width: 25, height: 25 }} />
                                    </View> 

                        </View>
                        <View style={Styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <Text style={Styles.vehicleDesc}>{"test"}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={Styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <Text style={Styles.text}>{item.mileage}{translate("Test 1")}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={Styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <Text style={Styles.text}>{"Test2"}</Text>
                        </View>



                                <View style={Styles.buttonContainer}>
                                    <Text style={Styles.watchListtext}>{"Test 3"}</Text>
                                </View> 

                    </View>


                </View>

            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
    );

}
```

Your Style

```
 listItemContainer: {
    marginTop: 7,
    //  marginBottom: 7,
    flexDirection: 'row',

    alignItems: 'flex-start',
},
listDesign: {

    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 6,
    width: '100%'
},
vehicleDesc: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#AA2328',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
},
text: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: Colors.black,
},
watchListtext: {
    marginLeft: 12,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: Colors.brandPrimary,
},
 imageLength: {
    width: '35%'
},
contentLength: {
    width: '65%'
},
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.creamyWhite,

},
  buttonContainer: {

    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 2

}, imageContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
justifySpaceAround:
{
    justifyContent:'space-around'
}
justifyEnd:
{
 justifyContent:'flex-end'
},
 coulmnAlign:
{
 flexDirection:'coumn'
}
```

You show empty data

```
   showEmptyListView = () => {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: Colors.white }}>{"No Data to Display"}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle a lot in style.
You only need 3 common tag: 
HorizontalContainer,
    VerticalContainer,
    ItemContainer,

```
export const VerticalContainer = styled.View({
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: (props) => props.backgroundColor || "#000"
});

export const HorizontalContainer = styled.View({
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: (props) => props.backgroundColor || "#000"
});

export const ItemContainer = styled.View({
    flex: (props) => props.flex || 1
});
```

Inside handle as you like:

```
<HorizontalContainer backgroundColor="#fff">
    <ItemContainer/>
    <ItemContainer flex=2></ItemContainer>
    <ItemContainer /> 
</HorizontalContainer >
```

Hope to help you!

Comment: in that code what is styled.View??I got an error from that